# Issue starting passenger on local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

Whenever I start passenger it throws a weird error

```
➜  my_app rvm:(ruby-2.0.0) git:(master) ✗ passenger start
=============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /home/user/apps/my_app/tmp/pids/passenger.3000.pid
Log file: /home/user/apps/my_app/log/passenger.3000.log
Environment: development
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0:3000/

You can stop Phusion Passenger Standalone by pressing Ctrl-C.
===============================================================================
[ 2013-10-29 12:56:59.8504 6769/7f7f22545700 Pool2/Spawner.h:738 ]: [App 6799 stdout] 
[ 2013-10-29 12:57:00.1106 6769/7f7f22545700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:849 ]: Could not spawn process for group /home/user/apps/my_app#default: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::handleErrorResponse(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&)' (SmartSpawner.h:455)
     in 'std::string Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::negotiatePreloaderStartup(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&)' (SmartSpawner.h:558)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::startPreloader()' (SmartSpawner.h:206)
     in 'virtual Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::spawn(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (SmartSpawner.h:744)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (Implementation.cpp:782)

[ 2013-10-29 12:57:00.1109 6769/7f7f0bfff700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1972 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session. An error occured while starting up the preloader.
Error page:
/Gemfile not found (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
  /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:16:in `build'
  /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
  /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
  /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
  /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
  /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
  /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:212:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:96:in `preload_app'
  /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:150:in `<module:App>'
  /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

When I visit localhost:3000 on my browser it shows these errors:

```
/Gemfile not found (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
  /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:16:in `build'
  /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:148:in `definition'
  /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
  /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
  /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
  /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
  /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:212:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:96:in `preload_app'
  /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:150:in `<module:App>'
  /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Passenger 4.0.19 was working well and still working well on `ruby 2.0.0-p0` but not working on `ruby 2.0.0-p247`. I upgraded the ruby version with rvm since other gems in my rails app weren't working, and now passenger is not working after this upgrade of ruby version. Has anybody seen this error before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem with a rails app on a virtual private server, I could run webrick but not passenger, thin or unicorn without getting

```
Error page:
/Gemfile not found (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
```

This ended up being a bug in an older version of rubygems-bundler.  This fixed the issue for me.

```
gem update rubygems-bundler
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

may be strange, but try `gem install bundler` and then `bundle install` again

Comment: this once did solved my problem, so I guess @surya might also be helped with this if incase he is going through the same situation...

Comment: Amit, I did bundle install, bundle update, many times. re-installed passenger gem two times, ran `passenger-install-apache2-module`. But, none of them seems to be working.. :(